# razor inline if statement in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, if-statement, razor

I need to write an inline razor if statement to set selected value of dropdownlist in javascript like this:

```
$.each(response,
    function (key, value) {
        $(Banner).append($("<option @(dataUi != null && dataUi.Fk_BannerId == value.Id ? "selected=\"selected\"" : "") value="
                        + value.Id + ">"
                        + value.Name + "</option>"));           
    }
);
```

but is says can not resolve symbol value
how can I use value.Id in this razor if statement?

Comment: razor is a template engine, all code that you want to execute in it will be run *before* the client sees the page, or can execute JavaScript. You can't use JS variables in there, as they don't have any value at the time razor runs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm writing this blind so please forgive any typo's.

Try something like this:

```
<script>
$.each(response, function (key, value) {
    var _dataUiID = "@dataUi.Fk_BannerId";
    var _selected = "";
    if(value.Id == _dataUiID) {
        _selected = "selected='selected'";
    } 
    $(Banner).append($("<option " + _selected + " value="
        + value.Id + ">"
        + value.Name + "</option>"));
    });
</script>
```

Sorry, not sure if `dataUi.Fk_BannerId` is numeric or a string so you may have to adjust `var _dataUiID = "@dataUi.Fk_BannerId";` a little...also to cater for `null`...